# Make own strchr() function but case-insensitive

Tags: c, char, c-strings, function-definition, strchr

My exercise requires that I can use case-insensitive input. My approch is that I use the tolower and toupper function.

How can I convert the array to lowercase letters?

```
void KULstrcichr(char *arr, char search)
{
    printf("Return value when uppercase character %c is passed to isupper(): %d\n", search, isupper(search));
    // The  strchr() function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character c in the string s.
    if (isupper(search))
    {
        printf("Groß\n");
        char lowercasesearch = tolower(search);
        printf("Das ist der Output: %s", arr);
        char *ptr = strchr(arr, lowercasesearch);
        printf("Das ist der Buchstabe: %s", ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Klein\n");
        char upercasesearch = toupper(search);
        printf("Das ist der Output: %s", arr);
        char *ptr = strchr(arr, upercasesearch);
        printf("Das ist der Buchstabe: %s", ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you post this exact question earlier today? Because I remember seeing the exact same title before. If you did it, then don't delete and repost questions, [edit] the ones you have to improve it instead.

Comment: C is not designed to work with Unicode text out of box. Your `ß` here is *not*, from C's perspective, Unicode code point U+00DF; it is an *8-bit integral value* that *incidentally happens* to equal 0xDF. Unless `char` on your platform is signed, which it legally may or may not be (and regardless of which it is, `char` is a separate, still numeric, type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`). That said `tolower` and `toupper` work on individual `char` values, and will give you a numeric result (the return type is `int` so that `-1` can be returned for errors).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I also recall seeing such a question, but this version looks much higher quality. Reposting questions is reasonable behaviour when the question basically needs to be rewritten from scratch; no reason the new version should be saddled with the old downvotes.

Comment: There was a question "I've no idea how to implement a case-insensitive version of `strchr()`" earlier.  There was no attempt to solve the problem.  This is much better; at least it shows a little thought and code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "`tolower` and `toupper` work on individual `char` values" is more like "...  on individual `unsigned char` values".

Comment: Anyway, part of the issue here is thinking about the problem logically. Simply converting the *input `char`* to lowercase (or uppercase) will not make a case-insensitive search possible. The point is to be able to *compare* `char`s that are in *the same* case. The search string potentially contains characters in mixed case; so logically, you need to *normalize* each value to the same case *as you proceed* through the comparison.

Comment: However, it is not useful or desired to change the data within the search string (the calling code will be surprised, since this code was only supposed to do a comparison, not modify its data). Instead, fix the case *as you retrieve* individual values from the array for comparison purposes. You are being asked to implement the internal logic yourself, *not* to prepare for a call to `strchr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the title of the question

> Make own strchr() function but case-insensitive

your code does not make any sense. You should write your own function similar to `strchr` that is declared in the C Standard  like

```
char * strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

The function should be declared and defined the following way

```
char * my_strchr( const char *s, int c )
{
    c = tolower( ( unsigned char )c );

    while ( *s && tolower( ( unsigned char ) *s ) != c ) ++s;

    return c == '\0' || *s != '\0' ? ( char * )s : NULL;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *my_strchr( const char *s, int c )
{
    c = tolower( ( unsigned char )c );

    while (*s && tolower( ( unsigned char )*s ) != c) ++s;

    return c == '\0' || *s != '\0' ? ( char * )s : NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    char *p = my_strchr( s, 'h' );

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        printf( "position = %td, substring = %s\n", p - s, s );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
position = 0, substring = Hello
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In the question the second parameter has the type char.

Comment: I have a problem using this code with my input. I'am sending an array with a string, and character with the the letter I'am searching for. (Hello, H) I'am getting only erros trying to get this code running. I don't understand the return code can you explan it?

Comment: @TheLuckyGuy See my appended answer with a demonstration program.

Answer (score 1):

*"How can I convert the array to lowercase letters?"* - you don't. Instead, check character by character until you've reached the end of the string.

- First convert the `char` you search for to lower (or upper) case.

  ```
  char lowsearch = tolower((unsigned char)search);
  ```
- Then loop `arr` until `*arr == '\0'` and check each character on the way:

  ```
  for(;*arr != '\0'; ++arr) {
      if(tolower((unsigned char)*arr) == lowsearch) return arr;
  }
  return NULL;
  ```

Note that this requires that you return a `char*` just like `strchr`, not `void`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I convert the array to lowercase letters? `void KULstrcichr(char *arr, char search)`

- To achieve "Make own `strchr()` function but case-insensitive", use an interface like `char *strchr(const char *s, int c);` for maximum compatibility with that standard function.
- Convert the `search` and `*arr` to a common case.  e.g. `tolower()`.  `tolower(int ch)` is defined for a `ch` in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.

Example:

```
char *TLG_strchr(const char *s, int c) {
  c = tolower((unsigned char)c);

  // str...() functions perform as if `s` was `unsigned char *`.
  const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char *) s;

  while (tolower(*us) != c && *us) {
    us++;
  }

  return tolower(*us) == c ? (char *) us : NULL;
}
```

---

Pedantic: `(unsigned char)*s` is incorrect for rare non-2's compliment machines with *signed* `char`.  Better as `*((unsigned char *)s)`, which is effectively what this answer does, to properly access negative `char` and distinguish +0 from -0.  This likely will be a non-issue for the next version of C as that is expected to require 2's compliment.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, Merci.

Answer (score 1):

This little assignment is more tricky than it looks:

- your code does not always work because you only search either for uppercase or for lowercase, depending on the case of `search`, which does not cover all cases (pun intended).
- using `strchr` first with uppercase, then with lowercase if uppercase was not found is still incorrect: you must find the first match for either case.
- you must also find the null terminator if `search` is `0`. Simple implementations usually fail this test.
- `tolower` and `toupper` are not defined for negative values different from `EOF`, hence they should not be passed `char` values that can be negative on platforms where `char` is signed by default. Casting the `char` argument as `(unsigned char)` is a simple way to avoid this issue.

Here is an example:

```
// using int c for compatibility with char *strchr(const char *s, int c)
char *KULstrcichr(const char *s, int c) {
    int uc = tolower((unsigned char)c);

    for (;; s++) {
        if (tolower(*(unsigned char *)s) == uc)
            return (char *)s;
        if (*s == '\0')
            return NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're using simple 8-bit ASCII characters, note that a given uppercase character is just (lowercase & 0x20). Take the input character and run it through strchr() twice: once with a lowercase version, and once with an uppercase version.

```
char *myStrchr(const char *s, char c) {
    char *pLower;
    char *pUpper;
    char *p;

    c |= 0x20;
    pLower = strchr(s, c);
    c &= ~0x20;
    pUpper = strchr(s, c);
    if (pLower == NULL) {
        p = pUpper;
    } else if (pUpper == NULL) {
        p = pLower;
    } else {
        p = (pLower < pUpper) ? pLower : pUpper;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Note: I don't think you want your function to be of type void.

EDIT: if your input string may contain characters other than letters, you'll need to bound-check before performing the searches.

Comment: Your code will search for `'@'` and then ```'`'``` — because you 'case-convert' every character, rather than only case-converting letters.  You should also run the second search with letters, and return the earlier of the two occurrences.  For example, if case-insensitively searching for `t` in `The first letter T is wanted`, the first search would find the `t` in `first`, but the second would find the `T` in `The`, and that's the match that should be returned.

Comment: I already noted your first point, but your second point is valid. I'll edit my answer...thanks.

Comment: @mzimmers You are probably right but what made you draw this conclusion?  _"it looks like you're using simple 8-bit ASCII characters"_

Comment: @TedLyngmo: it's more of an assumption than a conclusion, but in my experiences, chars are generally 8-bit values in C.